# Server refused public-key signature despite accepting key - putty

Tags: ssh, putty

I used puttygen to generate both my public and private key files (ssh2, 2048 bit). I have set up the settings in putty correctly and it is using the correct private key file. As for the public key, (I am using these keys for root) it is in `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys`

I have tried using `chmod` on `.ssh` to `700` and on `authorized_keys` to `400`. That did not do anything.

Does anyone have any recommendations?

edit: here's an `ls -ldZ` of my `.ssh` folder and `authorized_keys` file

```
drwx------ root root ?                                /root/.ssh
-rw------- root root ?                                /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Comment: give more information. what is remote server distro, version. is there any security layer between your client and server? (SELinux, iptables,...). Capture the audit log on your remote server when trying to connect to see any hint. Enable putty debug would be helpful.

Comment: It's running CentOS 6.7, and as far as I'm aware there is no security layer blocking anything. Where would I look for the audit log? I tried checking the auth log but it seems to not exist. As far as putty debugging goes, do you want the event log? I checked it and it contained quite a bit of information, but leading up to checking the key not much was helpful.

Comment: Trying to ssh from Linux box with `ssh -vvv` could be helpful, although it can contain some private information to be filtered.

Comment: `ls -ldZ ~ ~/.ssh ~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on server.

Comment: @Joel you should take a look at file `/var/log/audit/audit.log`. Also, update your answer with output of command from @Jakuje

Comment: Make sure no one's changed /etc/ssh/sshd_config to have something other than this, `AuthorizedKeysFile     %h/.ssh/authorized_keys`

Comment: Have you enabled root login in `/etc/sshd_config`? Have you logged in to the root account over SSH with another means of authentication? And go and find the logs — not `audit.log`, the “normal” system logs in `/var/log` (the file would be `auth.log` on Debian but IIRC CentOS organizes logs differently, look for the file whose time has changed). You will find the reason there. Edit your question to add the relevant part of that log.

Comment: I've updated my question with the `ls -ldZ` command. @EightBitTony it indeed has that. @Gilles I am unable to login to root via ssh, using just a password. However, I can su to root using the password. Sorry if this sounds dumb, but should I enable root login? Is that needed if you're logging in with keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the log `/var/log/secure` showed that it was just downright refused. I'm somewhat new to centos since I'm mainly a debian kind of guy, so I was unaware of `/var/log/secure`

After checking this and doing a bit of searching, it turns out `PermitRootLogin no` needs to be `PermitRootLogin without-password` if you want to specifically use just keys for root login. That did the trick. Thanks everyone for contributing.

Answer (score 11):

I also had this problem seemingly out of nowhere, but only with FileZilla and not Putty. (key based auth)

For me the solution was simple (when I read the tip [here](https://forum.filezilla-project.org/viewtopic.php?p=178201&sid=e1c1dc00e9d7e9967f66cdd8b58e26ce#p178201)) to just **[update Putty including Pageant](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/%7Esgtatham/putty/latest.html)**.

Answer (score 3):

Set `LogLevel` to `DEBUG` in `sshd_config`, and I think you'll find (in `auth.log` of course) a reason why you publick key is refused.

Comment: You don't even need to change the log level. A denied login is always logged with a reason, and usually that reason is enough to figure it out.

Comment: not always, in my case it was `sshd[xxxx]: Connection closed by authenticating user xxxx 10.x.x.x port xxxxx [preauth]` so something more verbose than default was needed

Answer (score 1):

We had the same error ("Server refused public-key signature despite accepting key") while trying to connect to ssh to a server using a key as root. It turned out that the problem was caused by the fact that the server's SSH configuration wasn't allowing the user `root` to use SSH keys.

Answer (score 1):

Some protocol deprecation in progress..

1. Upgrade putty to version 0.77 (that includes puttygen)
2. Run puttygen, load id_rsa file, generate new PPK (overwrite old one)

Comment: I'm trying to figure out if this is my issue since my key is from like 2012.  Can you link to more information?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem seemingly out of nowhere. Previously I'd added ssh keys and connected without issue. Even the SSH button to connect to the VM available through the Google Cloud Console website would fail to register keys.

The problem was that Google's Linux Guest Environment wasn't running. I resolved my issue by following the directions for [In-Place Install: Linux Guest Environment](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/linux-guest-environment#in_place).

Answer (score 0):

We upgraded Ubuntu from 18 to 20 and experienced that error message. For hours I tried to get RSA up and running again, but with no success.

In the end, the solution was to create an ECDSA key in putty and no changes to any ssh configs were necessary.